# WordPress Media Preview: A Preview for a PDF is Showing Black

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I want to upload a PDF on my WordPress site, but the preview image is coming up black. The PDF fully shows when linked on the front-end of the site.

This is the second time a black preview of a PDF has happened. The PDF is four pages long.

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: Read the comments of the user with the nickname **codeview** https://deliciousbrains.com/pdf-preview-images-wordpress-real-world/

Comment: WordPress 5.0.3 is what is being used

Comment: A workaround is suggested by user **bttrfly0213** on [the Wordpress support site](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pdf-thumbnail-generated-as-all-black/)